# argument of type "int *" is incompatible with parameter of type "int (*)[1000]"

Tags: c, matrix

i try this code to make a multiplication between matrices its work in my computer but if i try to run it in another its display me an error 
argument of type "int *" is incompatible with parameter of type "int (*)[1000]"
i think that the problem is that i made a dynamic allocation for a normal array but i use it as a 2D array...

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define M 1000
#define N 1000

void randmat (int mat[M][N],int,int);
void printmat (int mat1[M][N],int,int);

void msklret(int matrixA[M][N],int matrixB[M][N],int matrixC[M][N],int,int,int);
void main ()
{
int c1,c2,r1,r2; 
 int *mat1= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*M);
int *mat2= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*M);
int *mat3= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*M);


printf("enter the Dimensional of the matrix 1:\n");
scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);
printf("enter the Dimensional of the matrix 2:\n");
scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);
flushall();
while (c1!=r2)
{

printf("worng!!please enter a new Dimensional of the matrix 1:\n");
scanf("%d%d",&c1,&r1);
printf("please enter a new Dimensional of the matrix 2\n");
scanf("%d%d",&c2,&r2);
}



printf("random matrix 1:\n");
randmat(mat1,c1,r1);
printmat(mat1,c1,r1);
printf("random matrix 2:\n");
randmat(mat2,c2,r2);
printmat(mat2,c2,r2);
printf("the multiply of both matrix 1 and 2  :\n");
msklret(mat1,mat2,mat3,r1,c2,r2);
printmat(mat3,c2,r1);
getch();
}


void randmat (int matrix[M][N],int a,int b)
{
int i , j;



for(i=0;i<b;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<a;j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j]=rand()%90 + 1;
    }
}
}

void printmat (int matrix1[][N],int x,int y)
{
    int k,l;
for(k=0;k<y;k++)
{
    for(l=0;l<x;l++)
        printf(" %4d ",matrix1[k][l]);                                              
    printf("\n");
}
}

void msklret(int matrixA[M][N],int matrixB[M][N],int matrixC[M][N],int r1,int c2,int r2)
{

int i , j,l,MultiSum = 0;


for (i = 0; i < r1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < c2; j++)
    {
        for (l = 0; l < r2; l++)
            MultiSum += matrixA[i][l] * matrixB[l][j];

        matrixC[i][j] = MultiSum;
        MultiSum = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're right, your functions are expecting arguments of a different type. Why are you doing the memory allocation before you find out how big the arrays should be?

Comment: Please post a _minimal_ example that shows the same problem, and tell us which line the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: i tried to do it after knowing the rows and the columns but it give me another error.. i think i should allocate as a 2D array but i don't know how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
int *mat1= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*M);
int *mat2= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*M);
int *mat3= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*M);
```

to

```
int (*mat1)[N]= (int (*)[N])malloc(sizeof(int)*N*M);//No need to cast the return value of malloc
int (*mat2)[N]= (int (*)[N])malloc(sizeof(int)*N*M);
int (*mat3)[N]= (int (*)[N])malloc(sizeof(int)*N*M);
```

Comment: @user3653286 If it worked, then you encouraged to "upvote" and "accept" the answer provided by BLUEPIXY, by clicking on the upward-pointing arrow and the hollow checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Is this actually a legitimate way to allocate a 2D contiguous array? I've never seen it done without a loop before.

Comment: @TomFenech This is one way to allocate contiguous space as a two-dimensional array. Due to the array of pointers commonly used is not to use the linear region.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you said. Also, in your answer, you have stated that there is no need to cast the return value of `malloc` but you have cast it anyway. I think it would be helpful to explain these things in your answer.